# Alamofire cannot call value of non-function type

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "afternoon-plains-5526.herokuapp.com", parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in
        let json = JSON(response.data!)
        let token = json["token"].string
        response(token: token) //Error!
    }
```

I am getting an error saying "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Response'". What is the issue with this?

Comment: `response` is a parameter returned in the closure. It's not a (completion) function which can be called.